# Python script to traverse directory recursively, searching each .html and .php for a pattern

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python and need a script to traverse from a root folder searching each file for an occurrence of a string pattern and delete it(string pattern). Due to time constraints I can not learn enough Python and code it at the moment, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look to `os.listdir` and `glob`

Comment: what is that pattern? I am posting here the half code till finding each file. later you can open and write pattern changes on each file

Comment: Its for my site that's been compromised so going through a thousand files is not practical, just to give you the background.

Comment: The pattern is "<script src="http://cpm.36obuy.org/js/1.js"></script>"

Comment: *Due to time constraints I can not learn enough Python...*. You may find it a bit rude, but that's not conformant with this site policy. Give help: yes, do it for you: no.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this through python?

Otherwise I think with some bash-foo this should be easily doable:

find -> to find all .html and .php files
and then a combination of xargs and infile grepping or using sed should do the trick!

Comment: Yeah, you definitely make a valid point. Bash didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Even the Bash does some programming at back-end. In case if you need coding you can go through and extend it.

```
import os
fi = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('.html','.php')):
            fi.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            #print(os.path.join(root, file))


print fi[2] 
# get all files and work on each file
for filename in fi:
    with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if 'searchphrase' in line:
                # do your pattern search here
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you are looking for all files containing that pattern ?

One way to do it (I'm no Python pro, just trying to help with the knowledge I am recently acquiring, so this is also an exercise for me, don't hesitate bringing corrections, that would be great) :

```
for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(rootDir):
# search all files recursively

    for filename in filenames:
        if ".html" in filename or ".php" in filename:
        # open each htlm or php file to replace pattern

            with open(os.path.join(root,filename),"r+") as fileToCorrect:
                lines = fileToCorrect.readlines()
                fileToCorrect.seek(0)

                for line in lines:
                    line = line.replace(pattern,"")
                    fileToCorrect.write(line)
```

This is probably not optimal at all, and I hope you'll understand it all, but it should do the work :)

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a go and yes I want to delete that pattern from all files.